# eunit test for timeout

Tags: unit-testing, erlang, erlang-otp, gen-fsm, eunit

How can I test that a gen_fsm does indeed timeout with eunit?

```
{ok, GH} = gen_fsm:start_link(myFSM, [], []),
//after 15 sec it should timeout if no messages received. 
//What must I write here to test it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is one solution:

```
{ok, GH} = gen_fsm:start_link(myFSM, [], []),
Ref = erlang:monitor(process,GH),
receive
    {'DOWN', Ref, process, GH,  normal} ->
        test_passed
after 
    15000 ->
        ?assert("FSM did not die.") % will always fail
end.
```

Comment: I get: xxx_tests: xxx_timeout_test...*timed out*
undefined
=======================================================
  Failed: 0.  Skipped: 0.  Passed: 0.
One or more tests were cancelled.
error

Comment: solved, the msg wasn't about the process going down, but about the test itself. Enclosed it with {timout, 30, fun()-> *test code*}. And now it works.